# copying a range in Excel and pasting Outlook stuck at temp file

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA code that is copying a range in Excel and pasting into the body of an Outlook email. The code works on several of my colleagues computers but not mine. The code gets as far as creating the .temp file, populating the To:, CC: and Subject but nothing appears in the body. I am trying to paste HTML. I am thinking it's a setting or something like that, but I'm not sure where to start. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub CreateEmail()

   Dim OutApp As Object
   Dim OutMail As Object

   Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
   Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    datestr = Date

    sbj = "***"
    toStr = "****"
    Ccstr = "*****"

   Dim rng As Range
   Set rng = Nothing
   Set rng = Range("Flash")

On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
    .To = toStr
    .Display
    .CC = Ccstr
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = sbj & datestr
    .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng)


End With
On Error GoTo 0

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub

Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "/" & "temp" & ".htm"

    rng.Copy
Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
With TempWB.Sheets(1)
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
    .Cells(1).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    On Error Resume Next
    .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
    .DrawingObjects.Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
End With

    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
     SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
     Filename:=TempFile, _
     Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
     Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
     HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
    .Publish (True)
End With

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
RangetoHTML = ts.ReadAll
ts.Close
RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                      "align=left x:publishsource=")

TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

Kill TempFile

Set ts = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
Set TempWB = Nothing

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

End Function

Comment: Same homework question? http://stackoverflow.com/q/13418708/1584744

Comment: I checked the other "homework question". They don't want something printed in bold. My script will publish the To, CC and Subject properly, but doesn't paste the range selected in the Excel file. I don't think this is a coding issue since the script works on the computers of two of my colleagues, but not my own.

Comment: This code works on my computer although the Html is very poor quality.  Since you say it works "on several of my colleagues' computers but not mine", this is perhaps not surprising.  I suggest you try without the `On Error` statements.  `On Error Resume Next` means ignore any errors and do not tell the user.  Do you know the temp file is created?  Have you looked in your temporary folder and checked its contents?

Comment: Thanks, Tony. Yes, I have checked the Temp file and do see the contents within the spreadsheet opened. There is clearly a breakdown after the Temp file is created. I was curious to know what you meant by "the HTML is poor quality". How can it be "high quality"?

Comment: So the problem with the original code is that the columns on the sheet were displayed as numbers and not letters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opted to used this method instead. This pastes a range of excel, but not the HTML version. I did not need to use HTML. This works just as good, but without colors and such.

```
Sub SendFlash()
Dim rng As Range
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object

Set rng = Nothing
On Error Resume Next
Set rng = Range("K4:L8").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
On Error GoTo 0

If rng Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "The selection is not a range or the sheet is protected" & _
           vbNewLine & "please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
    Exit Sub
End If

With Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

toStr = "*"
Ccstr = "*"
sbj = "Tran"

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
    .To = toStr
    .CC = Ccstr
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = sbj & Date
    .Body = TableRangeToTabDelim(rng)
    .display
End With
On Error GoTo 0

With Application
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub

Function TableRangeToTabDelim(TableRange As Range) As String
Dim TableCols As Integer
Dim TableRows As Integer
Dim ReturnString As String

TableCols = TableRange.Columns.Count
TableRows = TableRange.Rows.Count

i = 1
j = 1

Do While i <= TableRows
    Do While j <= TableCols
        ReturnString = ReturnString & TableRange.Cells(i, j).Value
        If j <> TableCols Then
            ReturnString = ReturnString & Chr(9)
        End If
        j = j + 1
    Loop
    j = 1
    If i <> TableRows Then
        ReturnString = ReturnString & Chr(10)
    End If
    i = i + 1
Loop

TableRangeToTabDelim = ReturnString
End Function
```